# React not showing local images || load local image without importing them in react

Tags: reactjs, image

Sometime we can not import every image if number of images are so much or if we get path of image from database and that image is stored in local "images" folder and we can not import them while getting image from database dynamically.

So without importing them, is there a way to get that images?

1. Images are located in the `"/images"` folder in public folder that outside the "src" folder:

   [image]
2. Trying to access image by using the following code:
   `const path = "../images/"+ image_path ;`

   ```
   const Product = ({ item }) => {
     const src = `"/images/${item.img}`;

     return (
       <Container>
         <Circle />
         <Image src={src} />
         ...
       </Container>
     );
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If the images are stored in `/public/images` then all image URL's should start with an absolute path, e.g. `"/images"`, not `"../Image"`. `"../Image"` is a relative path and the app will try looking for an `Image` sibling directory for whatever the current URL path is. For example if a user is on `"/foo/bar"` and tries to load an image asset from `"../Images"` the source URL will look like `"/foo/Images"` and the directory and asset can't be found.

```
const Product = ({ item }) => {
  const src = `"/images/${item.img}`;

  return (
    <Container>
      <Circle />
      <Image src={src} />
      ...
    </Container>
  );
};
```

If you know ahead of time that ***all*** images are in the `/public/images` directory then you could also encode this as part of the `item.img` value in the data, then the UI code is a little simpler.

Example:

```
const Product = ({ item }) => (
  <Container>
    <Circle />
    <Image src={item.img} /> {/* "/images/1.jpg", "/images/2.jpg", etc */}
    ...
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: @RahulBhati Hi, did this answer help address/resolve your question/issue?